# Scriptlet v. EL Processing in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

Whilst firmly in the EL camp these days, I was looking at a JSP with scriptlets and found I had a technical question about how they're processed vs the EL equivalent.

Say you had a Java class with String constants called **Strings**, and one of the constants it contained is called *string1*. If you have a JSP with the following scriptlet used more than once

```
<%=Strings.string1%>
```

does this result in extra processing time in the compilation of the JSP vs. multiple uses of the equivalent EL object reference? I was just wondering in case I end up in a design-philosophy discussion soon.

Comment: This is compiled to `out.print(Strings.string1);`. Why do you think it would result in extra-processing time to compile that?

Comment: I was just wondering if it did, is all. I'm looking for philosophical ammunition in case I end up in a debate about switching these scriptlets to EL, so I was trying to see if that would be one more bullet to add to my belt...

Comment: What would be the EL equivalent of this, BTW? Would it be the one to require extra processing?

Comment: @developerwjk, you would add the string object to your ModeAndView while still in the controller component of your application, then wherever you needed it, the EL reference would be ${string1}. I probably picked a trivial example, as it seems like my question would be more relevant if the code in the scriptlet was a method call, e.g., `Strings.getString1()`